# How to check if a node is a link in h5py?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

How can I know if a node is a `SoftLink` or `HardLink` or `ExternalLink`?

For instance, providing `fh = h5py.File('test.h5')` and `/soft_link` a `SoftLink`, I tried `type(fh['soft_link'])` and it is shown that it's of the type of `Group`, the same as a regular `Group` node.

BTW, it seems `fh.visititems` does not visit the `Link` nodes, I can understantd that this can avoid to visit the target nodes of `SoftLink` and `HardLink` twice, but why `ExternalLink` is also neglected?

Answer (score 3):

It is a little bit late but it may be useful for someone. Actually the current version of `h5py` supports it (I don't know if it was the case back in time).

Actually it is quite easy:

```
is_soft_link = isinstance(fh.get('soft_link', getlink=True), h5py.SoftLink)
```

Just replace `h5py.SoftLink` by `h5py.HardLink` or `h5py.ExternalLink` for the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this is done in `h5py` but, in case you are not bound to a specific library, this can be done as follows in [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com):

```
HDFql.execute("SHOW TYPE my_dataset")

HDFql.cursor_next()

type = HDFql.cursor_get_int()

if (type & HDFql.SOFT_LINK):
   print('IT IS A SOFT LINK')
elif (type & HDFql.EXTERNAL_LINK):
   print('IT IS AN EXTERNAL LINK')
else:
   print('IT IS A HARD LINK')
```

Please check section `6.7.7` in HDFql [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) for additional information.